# Kinect - record and use video

Tags: video, load, kinect

I am planning to buy Kinect for Windows because I am going to make a school project with one friend. My question is really simple - can I record a video of some gestures with the Kinect and then send it to him because he can't buy a Kinect. Will he be able to load the video and use it at runtime like a stream coming from kinect so both of us can work on the project. The project will be written in C# and probably using the Microsoft's Kinect SDK, and OpenCV or OpenNI if needed.

Comment: Exact dupe of other question about using Kinect offline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: yes. It's up to what SDK you use.

In addition to the KinectSDK, [Kinect Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj650892.aspx) is a handy tool for recording and using kinect data.

OpenNI also allows kinect data to be saved. There's an API for that, but the simplest way to start with is the [NiViewer Sample](http://openni.org/docs2/Reference/samples.html) (Press s to start recording, x to stop). On Windows .oni files will register with the application so you can simple open the file to view it or analyze it (for example on a different machine with OpenNI but no Kinect).

I haven't tried combining the KinectSDK and OpenNI, but the [Kinect-MSSDK-OpenNI-bridge](http://code.google.com/p/kinect-mssdk-openni-bridge/) project looks promising.

In conclusion, think about the functionalities you need to use (e.g. depth data, rgb data, skeleton tracking, audio data, motor control, accelerometer, etc.). and the target operating system. There are pros and cons on both sides:

- KinectSDK offers audio/motor/accelerometer control, but is Windows 7 only
- OpenNI doesn't offer the above(although it supports depth/rgb/skeleton data), but is cross platform and as of more recent releases [integrates quite nicely with OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_highgui.html#using-kinect-and-other-openni-compatible-depth-sensors)

Comment: Please note that to use Kinect Studio you still need to have a Kinect connected to your PC, so a record file only is not enough.

Comment: @catflier so my friend has to buy a Kinect too? Is that what you are telling me?

Comment: If you want to use Kinect Studio and Microsoft SDK you do need a Kinect indeed (and actually for the moment a recorded stream needs to be played with the same kinect connected) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131036.aspx

Comment: If you want to use only the skeleton tracking (not video, not depth stream) you can generate a file by yourself containing the skeleton joint positions in some format (xml, csv, ...) and "play it" anywhere.